# Searching and coloring text in a pdf file using c#

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm afraid I don't even know where to start with the following problem, so if any of you would give me some pointers, I'd appreciate it.

I need to load and display a pdf file. Then I need to search and colorize a few words of interest in said pdf file (noting position, page, etc) using C#. I have Adobe Acrobat 7 professional, so I have some of the COM tools.

Regards.

Comment: Are you required to then save the changed pdf back out?

Comment: Adam, that would be nice in principle, but no. The objective of the app is to just research the use of some words in a subset of pdf documents and cross-reference them with the graphs that appear in these pdfs. So keeping state would be nice, but I can also maintain state by populating a list box with the matched word's information.

Comment: @Nate: I've no idea what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My [company](http://www.atalasoft.com) sells .NET PDF components that can be used to extract text from documents as well as display pages.  We have [a demo here](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/31appsin31days/archive/2008/05/14/web-pdf-library-searcher.aspx) which does full text search and highlighting of a PDF document, which is very close to what you want to do.  As long as the changes don't need to be permanent, this technique will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iText](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) to load, modify and re-save the document. If you can get on by just launching Acrobat afterwards, you're home.

Comment: but i can't search for text, can I?

Comment: oh yes. you can break up the pdf in all its pieces and manipulate them at your wish.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating a PDF file is hard since pdf is a hard format. There are good libraries does great job such as [ITextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html).

But my advise is convert the pdf file to html and play with the html output. Then display it on a WebBrowser control.

I know this is **an ugly solution**. Also this ugly solution has another ugly solution for converting a pdf file to html.

See: http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-convert-pdf-file-to-text-in.html